# FirstOrDefault returns NullReferenceException if no match is found

Tags: c#, lambda

Here is my code:

```
string displayName = Dictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.ID == long.Parse(options.ID)).Value.DisplayName;
```

The code works fine if `x.Value.ID` matches `options.ID`. However, I get a `NullReferenceException` if it doesn't.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault` returns the default value of a type if no item matches the predicate. For reference types that is `null`.  Thats the reason for the exception.

So you just have to check for `null` first:

```
string displayName = null;
var keyValue = Dictionary
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.ID == long.Parse(options.ID));
if(keyValue  != null)
{
    displayName = keyValue.Value.DisplayName;
}
```

But what is the key of the dictionary if you are searching in the values? A `Dictionary<tKey,TValue>` is used to find a value **by the key**. Maybe you should refactor it.

Another option is to provide a default value with `DefaultIfEmpty`:

```
string displayName = Dictionary
    .Where(kv => kv.Value.ID == long.Parse(options.ID))
    .Select(kv => kv.Value.DisplayName)   // not a problem even if no item matches
    .DefaultIfEmpty("--Option unknown--") // or no argument -> null
    .First();                             // cannot cause an exception
```

Comment: The first solution didn't work. I am getting the same exception. 
The second one worked for me.Thank you.

Comment: I think that if it's a dictionary we can check if item key is null, not the item it self. The item will be the default item:
var item = dict.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Key == something);
if (!(item.Key == null))

Answer (score 22):

You can use a combination of other LINQ methods to handle not matching condition:

```
var res = dictionary.Where(x => x.Value.ID == someID)
                    .Select(x => x.Value.DisplayName)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty("Unknown")
                    .First();
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply use the question mark trick for null checks:

```
string displayName = Dictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.ID == long.Parse(options.ID))?.Value.DisplayName ?? "DEFINE A DEFAULT DISPLAY NAME HERE";
```

Answer (score 4):

That is because `FirstOrDefault`can return `null` causing your following `.Value` to cause the exception. You need to change it to something like:

```
var myThing = things.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == idToFind);

if(myThing == null)
    return; // we failed to find what we wanted
var displayName = myThing.DisplayName;
```

Comment: I get the exception in the first line.So it didn't work.Thank u though.

Comment: Then your dictionary is probably null, or you have keys stored for a null value.

You are also using a dictionary wrong, to retrieve values it's most common to use the index: []
Are you using the dictionary by choice? Perhaps you are deserializing JSON and it gives you a dictionary when you probably want a List instead?

Answer (score 3):

To add to the solutions, here is a LINQ statement that might help

```
Utilities.DIMENSION_MemTbl.Where(a => a.DIMENSION_ID == format.ContentBrief.DimensionID).Select(a=>a.DIMENSION1).DefaultIfEmpty("").FirstOrDefault();
```

The result will be an empty string if the result of the query is a null..

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for those of us who need a visual write up (like me :)

In the code screenshot below, a `NullReferenceException` will be thrown, the root cause is the `ReferenceIdentification_02` property.

[image]

When debugging, we see that the `orderLine.REF` array, I am querying does not include a matching object whose `ReferenceIdentificationQualifier_01` value `== "RU"`, so at that point `FirstOrDefault()` return value is `NULL`

[image]

to prevent the `NullReferenceException`, I do a `FirstOrDefault()` on the `orderLine.REF` array first. If the returned value is not `null` then I retrieve the value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i assume you are working with nullable datatypes, you can do something like this:

```
var t = things.Where(x => x!=null && x.Value.ID == long.Parse(options.ID)).FirstOrDefault();
var res = t == null ? "" : t.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use  with 'Where' statement with  `FirstOrDefault()`.
like this.

```
 var modelItem =  _dbcontext.ModelName.Where(n => n.NewsTagId == newsTag.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

It returns first item if does not match query.
It is better practice to check the NULL after query.

```
  if(modelItem == null)
  {
       return "Not Found."
  }
  else
  {
       // continue process
  }
```

Comment: This would still throw that exception.